# WebSocket is undefined on IE depending on the browser url. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, websocket

my simple websocket.html is like this below

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function webSocketTest(){
    if ('WebSocket' in window)
    {
        alert('supported');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('not supported');
    }
}

webSocketTest();

</script>
```

and I can get 'supported' message on chrome wherever it is.

But on IE (both 10 and 11)

1. If I open that html file with the browser directly(locally), it works fine. 
    I can get the 'supported' message.
2. But, if I put that html file under apache or IIS and open it by url, it says 'not supported'. 
   (ex. http://test.mysite.com/websocket.html 
   and of course, I set the hosts 
   file like, 127.0.0.1 test.mysite.com)
3. I set the same folder as home directory with two different url. One for 'test.abc.com/websocket.html' and the other for 'test.ddd.com/websocket.html'. Strangely, first one didn't work, but the second works well.(abc.com is my company name, actually it's not abc, it's another name.. )
   abc.com could be set as the trusted site once and removing it also doesn't work. :(

anybody knows what's the problem?

Comment: Is some configuration need to be set for Apache and IIS to support WebSocket?

Comment: I don't know the reason exactly. I put that html file into my NAS server. but it works well on it, but I didn't set any configuration on my NAS.  :(

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the problem at last.
Open Tools-Compatibility View setting. and then uncheck all the boxes.

I had added abc.com site to this compability setting list once before. Removing it also didn't worked at that time, but after unchecking all the checkboxes it's working now.

I hope this will help those who have this issue.